# Clickhouse import of "tombstone" Kafka messages with Kafka Engine as RawBLOB

Tags: apache-kafka, clickhouse

We are using Clickhouse to read messages from Kafka as RawBLOB, which used to work for our use case.
However since we updated Clickhouse from 21.2.3.15 to 23.3.13.6 **Kafka Engine is not reading "tombstone" messages**.
Those messages have null as messsage content and are used by Kafka Streams and CDC tools to indicate deletion of of a key.

Before the update such messages were "automagically" saved as empty strings, which was probably not accurate, but worked for us.
Now I don't know how to read such a message.
Looking at https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/13564 it seems RawBLOB should handle such case.

To reproduce the issue:

```
# produce to topic
[appuser@broker bin]$ kafka-console-producer --broker-list broker:29092 --property "parse.key=true" --property "key.separator=;" --property "null.marker=NULL" --topic topic1
>key1;message1
>key2;NULL
>key3;message3
```

Initial setup that worked for us:

```sql
-- remember to rename consumer group "group0" when creating other kafkatables so the test runs from beginning of topic

CREATE TABLE kafkatable0 (
    message String
) ENGINE = Kafka('broker:29092', 'topic1', 'group0', 'RawBLOB');

CREATE TABLE table0 (key String,message String)
ENGINE = MergeTree()
ORDER BY key;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW mv0 TO table0 AS
SELECT 
    _key as key,
    message as message
FROM kafkatable0;
```

Produces results:

```
# on clickhouse 21.2.3.15
f871a738a76c :) select * from table0

SELECT *
FROM table0

Query id: 0ef2a5e5-5175-4927-b29f-f5ed11bae947

┌─key──┬─message──┐
│ key1 │ message1 │
│ key2 │          │
│ key3 │ message3 │
└──────┴──────────┘

3 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.002 sec.
```

and after update:

```
# on clickhouse 21.9.2.17 up to latest
ca66e3ca8087 :) select * from table0

SELECT *
FROM table0

Query id: e6e54b98-5926-479d-8b6c-c8ae5c04e863

┌─key──┬─message──┐
│ key1 │ message1 │
│ key3 │ message3 │
└──────┴──────────┘

2 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.002 sec.
```

First idea was to add default value to String fields:  (message String DEFAULT '')
but it is not supported by latest Kafka engine:

```
Code: 36. DB::Exception: Received from localhost:9000. DB::Exception: KafkaEngine doesn't support DEFAULT/MATERIALIZED/EPHEMERAL expressions for columns. See https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/engines/table-engines/integrations/kafka/#configuration. (BAD_ARGUMENTS)
```

Second idea is to add nullable message to kafkatable and table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE kafkatable1 (
    message Nullable(String)
) ENGINE = Kafka('broker:29092', 'topic1', 'group11', 'RawBLOB');

CREATE TABLE table1 (key String,message Nullable(String) )
ENGINE = MergeTree()
ORDER BY key;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW mv1 TO table1 AS
SELECT 
    _key as key,
    message as message
FROM kafkatable1;
```

Still no success, only key1, key3 in the table.
Finally adding kafka_handle_error_mode='stream' and related columns:

```sql
CREATE TABLE kafkatable2 (
    message Nullable(String)
) 
ENGINE = Kafka
SETTINGS kafka_broker_list = 'broker:29092',
kafka_topic_list = 'topic1',
kafka_group_name = 'group22',
kafka_format = 'RawBLOB',
kafka_handle_error_mode='stream';

CREATE TABLE table2 (key String,error Nullable(String), rawmessage Nullable(String), message Nullable(String) )
ENGINE = MergeTree()
ORDER BY key;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW mv2 TO table2 AS
SELECT 
    _key as key,
    _error as error,
    _raw_message as rawmessage,
    message as message
FROM kafkatable2;
```

gives same result - tombstone for key2 is skipped without error message.

*(Additionally not related to our case, but key of the message also can be null in kafka, but in the documentation https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/engines/table-engines/integrations/kafka#configuration, we can see that for virtual column:
_key — Key of the message. Data type: String.
which cannot work.)*

**What is currently the correct way to read tombstone messages (as RawBLOB) into Clickhouse?**